# Show that $\mathcal{P}_{0}^{s}(F)$ is not a Measure

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading Falconer's book "Fractal Geometry" and I have got to the part where he talks about the Packing Dimension.

**Definition.** For $s\geq0$ and $\delta>0$, $\mathcal{P}_{\delta}^{s}(F)=\sup\{\sum_{i}|B_{i}|^{s}\}$, where the supremum is over all packings of the Borel set $F\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ by *disjoint* balls of radii at most $\delta$ and with centres in $F$.

He states that "Since $\mathcal{P}_{\delta}^{s}(F)$ decreases as $\delta$ decreases, $$\mathcal{P}_{0}^{s}(F)=\lim_{\delta\to0}\mathcal{P}_{\delta}^{s}(F)$$ exists. However, $\mathcal{P}_{0}^{\delta}(F)$ is not a measure."

**However, he doesn't explain how we know that it isn't a measure.**

*Hint.* Consider countable dense sets.

**My Question:** How do I show that $\mathcal{P}_{0}^{\delta}$ does not define a measure?

**My attempt so far** is pitiful really. I think I need to show that, for a countable sequence of dense sets $F_{1},F_{2},\ldots$, $$\mathcal{P}_{0}^{s}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}F_{i}\right)\not\leq\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathcal{P}_{0}^{s}(F_{i})$$ which shows that $\mathcal{P}_{0}^{s}$ is **not** a measure.

Comment: [This wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_dimension) states that $P_0^s$ is a _pre-measure_, not a measure.  A [pre-measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-measure) _is_ countably additive.  The issue is that it isn't always defined for all subsets (I think, if someone could verify this it'd be good).

Comment: @Mark Oh ok, so it is true that $\mathcal{P}_{0}^{s}(\emptyset)=0$ and  $\mathcal{P}_{0}^{s}(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}(F_{i}))=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{P}_{0}^{s}(F_{i})$ for any countable sequence. Do you know of an example for which it is not defined?

Comment: While this conflicts what I said earlier/my interpretation of the wiki page, look at [chapter 4](https://www.math.unm.edu/~loring/graduate_students/DaveWorthThesis.pdf).  I know relatively little about all of this, but this seems promising at least.

Comment: @Mark That looks interesting. Can you tell me what you make of Lemma 4.0.15 (page 50)? I think that's the one I need.

Comment: I agree it looks like what you want (That's why I linked it).  Unfortunately, I have no real experience with this, so you'll need to wait for someone with more experience to answer any questions you have.

Comment: Oh ok, well thank you for your help :)